# Catch zoom/pan move in codenameone

Tags: google-maps, codenameone

Hi i am building a gps app with codenameone. I use the native googlemapcn1lib. I was wondering how i can catch zoomlevel changed. 
I want to hide/show markers on the map at a zoomlevel.
I could do it with a timer but maybe there is a native method in the googlemapscn1lib.
Somebody a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Use `addMapListener(MapListener)` e.g.:

```
mapContainer.addMapListener((Component source, int zoom, Coord center) -> {
    // here you can act on the map directly after every pan/zoom change
});
```